# Why Samsung tablet 4 restarts while usb debugging with eclipse?

Tags: tabs, restart

I am using my Samsung tab4 for android testings. I am use to test straight through the cable on the tab. Suddenly it is getting restart when I deploy a application to tab from today. Is that a serious issue. And can I recover this by rebooting the tab.

Comment: If your question will be closed as offtopic, I suggest to re-ask it on http://android.stackexchange.com , where it probably won't.